# Which preposition is best for investments? On or from?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

10000 = the money you have to invest

> 1. I made 200 dollars **on** 10000 in 2 months.
> 2. I made 200 dollars **from** 10000 in 2 months

Which preposition should I use: *on* or *from*?

Comment: I think either one works fine. I like _from_ a smidgeon better, but have no problem with _on_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

1. [Make money on money](https://www.oldmutual.co.za/personal/investments-and-savings/unit-trusts/learn/invest-in-your-life/make-money-on-money)
2. [Make money with money](http://www.investorguide.com/article/14267/make-money-money-d1113/)
3. [Make money from money](http://www.makemoneyinlife.com/how-to-make-money-from-money-learn-the-best-ways-of-making-money-work-for-you.html)

According to Google search "**with**" is the most popular preposition.